# Why does my recursive function return "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, recursion, undefined

The function is returning `undefined` and it is a simple binary search code in JavaScript. When I checked with a `console.log()` the function is indeed working. Below is my source code:

```
var array=[1,2,3,2,4,5,6,8,7,8,9];
var searching= 3;
var starting = 0;
var ending = array.length-1;

var result = binarysearch(array,searching,starting,ending);
console.log(result); // throws undefined

function binarysearch(data,target,start,end){

var mediane = Math.round((start+end)/2);

if (data[mediane] == target) return mediane;  // console.log(mediane) gives 2 
if (data[mediane] > target) binarysearch(data,target,start,mediane-1);
if (data[mediane] < target) binarysearch(data,target,mediane+1,end);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple. Use `return` to follow the call-stack.

```
var array=[1,2,3,2,4,5,6,8,7,8,9];
var searching= 3;
var starting = 0;
var ending = array.length-1;

var result = binarysearch(array,searching,starting,ending);
console.log(result); // throws undefined


function binarysearch(data,target,start,end){

var mediane = Math.round((start+end)/2);

if(data[mediane] == target) return mediane;  // console.log(mediane) gives 2 
if ( data[mediane] > target) return binarysearch(data,target,start,mediane-1);
if ( data[mediane] < target) return binarysearch(data,target,mediane+1,end);

}
```

---

Explanation:

When you use a recursive call, the control goes from one function branch to another. In order to return a definite value, you need to pass the control (the function context, or the thing which knows where the program's execution is right now). You were not returning the recursive branches; this meant that the execution stack was creating a new function and, since it wasn't getting an output, treating it as a separate branch.

When you do the `return`, the context knows that it has to branch the function out and use the final return value: in this case `2`. I hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `return` keyword in your recursive call to `binarysearch`.Without `return` you function will obviously return `undefined`.

```js
var array=[1,2,3,2,4,5,6,8,7,8,9];
var searching= 3;
var starting = 0;
var ending = array.length-1;

var result = binarysearch(array,searching,starting,ending);
console.log(result); // throws undefined


function binarysearch(data,target,start,end){

var mediane = Math.round((start+end)/2);

if(data[mediane] == target) return mediane;  // console.log(mediane) gives 2
if ( data[mediane] > target) return binarysearch(data,target,start,mediane-1);
if ( data[mediane] < target) return binarysearch(data,target,mediane+1,end);

}
```

Comment: Beat you to it! ;)